# How to generate t3d file automatically?

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-8.x

I am trying to create a data.t3d file for my TYPO3 sitepackage.
How can I generate this file based on my custom configuration automatically without usind the wizard every time?
I am using TYPO3 8.7.2
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First of all the most important question: How often do you generate this file? Please note that this is no backup! In most cases you create your sitepackage, export the file and place it in the Initialisation directory. So there is no need to do it often.

One solution to have the same settings for every export (which is more useful I think) is to create a "Preset".

**How to create a preset?**
You can create a preset when opening the import/export-module and changing to the "File & Preset"-Tab.
Enter a title for your preset and click "Save".

**How to load a preset?**
To load a preset you select the preset in the "File & Preset"-Tab and press "Load".

Hopefully this will help you.

Comment: My intention is to keep my local vagrant environment up to date in relation to the live environment. Therefore a daily updating gitable solution  would by nice to have.

Comment: In this case you should have a look on the "typo3_console" (https://github.com/TYPO3-Console/typo3_console) and the commands "database:export" and "database:import"

Comment: Yes, I had the same idea but it is not so comfortable like putting the data.t3d file into the Initialisation-folder. In addition I wasn't sure if the t3d file will do more than just running database queries.